# Rails column type for numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm storing numbers such as

```
2,000

5,000

10,000
```

in a database with an 'integer column'. When I display them on the app, they're showing up like

```
2.0
5.0
```

Is there a column type I can use to make them show up "as is." I tried string before but string doesn't sort well.

Comment: Are you encoding them as a foreign language? The only thing I can think of is that some European languages use commas like Americans use decimals.

Comment: not that i'm aware of. I'm in North America, settings should all be for English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers should come out like integers. If you try to insert "2,000" internally rails is effectively doing to do a to_i on it which will be 2. (try this on irb "2,000".to_i and "2_000".to_i to see how ruby deals with integer conversions).

Now if you insert 2000 and you get 2000.0 that is not natural or expected for an integer column. I suspect there is some post processing going on on the attribute or that your database is decimal/float column.

Rails Console =>

```
"2,000".to_i => 2
"2_000".to_i => 2000
helper.number_to_currency(2000) => "$2,000.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix this, I entered the number in the database without the comma. Then the numbers showed up on the app like 10000.0 and I used `number_to_currency` to change the number to make it look like a dollar value

Comment: This is the correct approach. You should not handle display logic in the database. Represent it in the most basic form, then use the template logic to handle presentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can also enter in integers like this

```
10_000
5_000
2_000
```